# Python transparent weak referencing

Tags: python

Python 3.6

How would I go about creating a 'transparent' `weakref.ref`.

So I don't have to use the `__call__()` method?

I can just use `y.value`

```
class integer():
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value

x = integer(5)
y = weakref.ref(x)

print(y.__call__().value)
```

output:

```
5
```

Comment: You're not supposed to use `__call__` explicitly; it's just `y().value`. You can get `y.value` with a `weakref.proxy` (as you'd have seen if you checked the docs), but don't use those, because it's way easier to screw up with those.

Comment: @user2357112 - how do you think I found out about the `weakref` module?

Comment: Thanks though, that seems like the easiest option. I want to create different 'views' of a large set of data. Using a proxy object sounds perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use:

```
class integer():
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value

x = integer(5)
y = weakref.proxy(x)

print(y.value)
```

outputs:

```
5
```